# Microsoft Access(2007-2010) Form Header Input Controls Locked Out

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Got a weird one here.  On newly created forms, I am having an issue with input fields placed in the Form Header.  These "Unbound" fields are generally used for searching/filtering the form and I am having issues with both text boxes and combo boxes.  The fields locked setting is set to No and the enabled setting is set to Yes.  The Form's Data Entry, Additions, Edits, Filters is set to Yes and Deletions is set to No.

On form load, when a user attempts to type into the search field nothing happens.  No errors are reported at the bottom of Access.  The weird part is if I go into design mode, then back to view mode, the field works as designed.  The forms query looks at this field to filter the form out, so I am wondering if the query is locking this filed out when the form is loaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of pulling the search value from your form, you could use the search value to set a filter or construct a `WHERE` clause for the record source and do a `requery`.

Comment: What ever search method I use, the problem still exists.  The field the user types in their search criteria is bugged and acts as if it is locked.  The user can focus on it and the field is enabled, but when a user types anything on their keyboard there is no characters displaying in the field.  I truly believe this is a glitch with my current version of Access,  What tells me it must be a bug is that this issue occurs on new forms I create and it is fixed when I enter design mode and come back to form view.  Just wondering if anyone else is experiencing this and has any work around.  Thanks,